Cannot connect to ESXi after removing uplink from vSwitch
In a lab environment I removed the one and only uplink from vSwitch (I wanted to add the nic to another vSwitch - but I lost connectivity). Now I can't connect to ESXi. I don't have vCenter.
Is there a way to add the network interface back to vSwitch and restore connectivity? I can't SSH to ESXI either. Is re-install the only way?

You can enable shell access from the ESXi console: https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/ccfb410a-e271-4720-859d-ad9f108fee75/f1fa6c4a-7c5c-4422-90bd-fec64b2a10ca/doc/cos_upgrade_technote.1.4.html.
From the ESXi shell, you should be able to add back the uplink to the vSwitch: https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/24be7af7-d9cd-48d9-bab8-8c91614be19d/0ca33108-8017-4b40-86b9-f066456894ea/doc/GUID-4E2F8392-2CC4-4DC8-AED9-8C5ACA12E27A.html

Nice. That worked. I was able to add the nic. I also had to restart Management network for it to start working.
